# Upload files from google drive to server in Ionic application

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, ionic-framework, google-drive-api

I'm new to Angular and Ionic. I'm trying to create a page where a user can upload the file from google drive to the server. He has to do it by logging into Google drive then choose the file from google drive and upload into the server. I don't have any idea of how to start and where to start. If you can guide me or give me an example, it would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting, I would recommend to start reading first about the documents regarding the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) and Ionic Development/ AngularJS. This would help you understand how Drive API works and what are the available functions on the API you use (REST, iOS, Android). These document can help you understand the flow and some code samples that will explain how the function will work. You can also find [handling of errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors), [best practices](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/practices) and [performance tips](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/performance) to help you improve your app.

Here are some github repo that can help you with the implementation:

- [Ionic](https://github.com/Raza-Dar/ionic-google-drive)
- [AngularJS](https://github.com/pinoyyid/ngDrive)

Hope this helps.