# how to integrate google drive upload api in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How to upload my camera image or gallery image using google drive upload api in `ionic/angularjs`. I checked following link but not get any working example.

[Upload files from google drive to server in Ionic application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410101/upload-files-from-google-drive-to-server-in-ionic-application)

Comment: The 'exact code' will depend on your implementation and we can't guess what that might be. You will learn much more if you read the documentation in your linked answer and write the code yourself.

Comment: Thanks @thodic. But i cant find any working example for ionic or angular. you have any link.

Comment: did you find any example ?